# How curl Pod k8S

Tags: curl, kubernetes

I have installed 1 master and two nodes.
I have created namespace for a POD.
I have launched a Yaml file provided by linux academy on a tutorial see below
[tutorial](https://linuxacademy.com/cp/courses/lesson/course/3606/lesson/2/module/267)
But I when I do my command curl it's doesn't work.

```
[rbo@K8SMaster ~]$ curl 10.244.1.2:80
```

Yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: examplepod
  namespace: pod-example
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: html
    emptyDir: {}
  containers:
  - name: webcontainer
    image: nginx
    volumeMounts:
    - name: html
      mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
  - name: filecontainer
    image: debian
    volumeMounts:
    - name: html
      mountPath: /html
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
    args:
      - while true; do
         date >> /html/index.html;
         sleep 1;
        done
```

Command:

```
    [rbo@K8SMaster ~]$ kubectl get nodes
NAME        STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION
k8smaster   Ready    master   4d17h   v1.15.3
k8snode1    Ready    <none>   3d23h   v1.15.3
k8snode2    Ready    <none>   3d16h   v1.15.3


kubectl create namespace podexample
kubectl create -f pod-example.yml
pod/examplepod created

kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   coredns-5c98db65d4-9929x            1/1     Running   216        4d17h
kube-system   coredns-5c98db65d4-mb9t2            1/1     Running   216        4d17h
kube-system   etcd-k8smaster                      1/1     Running   1          4d17h
kube-system   kube-apiserver-k8smaster            1/1     Running   1          4d17h
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-k8smaster   1/1     Running   1          4d17h
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-2d28b         1/1     Running   1          3d23h
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-kpnqs         1/1     Running   1          3d16h
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-zbh7z         1/1     Running   1          4d17h
kube-system   kube-proxy-24msd                    1/1     Running   1          4d17h
kube-system   kube-proxy-ghngr                    1/1     Running   0          3d16h
kube-system   kube-proxy-mg25z                    1/1     Running   1          3d23h
kube-system   kube-scheduler-k8smaster            1/1     Running   1          4d17h
podexample    examplepod                          2/2     Running   0          5m33s
```

Thanks for help and sorry i'am newbies with K8S

Comment: What is the error you get from CURL and where did you get that IP address from?

Comment: No erreur the command is pending, Il must do ctrl+c to kill the process. I'am trying to launch the curl from the master.

Comment: You have to provide more information:
1- provide output of `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -owide` and `kubectl get nodes -owide`. 2- Provide coredns logs, 216 restarts is not expected behaviour. 3- check flanner logs if there is anything suspicious. 4- Provide output of `kubectl get event --all-namespaces` 5- check if you can ping flanner ip from `ip addr`. 6- check webservice container if there is anything in file `cat /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html`.

Comment: Did you use kubeadm to create cluster on your pc or you crated this cluster in cloud?

Comment: Guys Sorry I have let this exercice. I'm trying to understand the basic command. I think I missed lot of basic principe. I have started new manifest and create simply pod and used port-forward command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think curl command is right but nginx container have nothing to return on port 80 . Make sure pvc is created and manually check this directory -> /usr/share/nginx/html if it have index.html or not and also check whether index.html file have read permission.